# Rsync to Google Compute engine Instance from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, rsync, google-compute-engine

I want to send files from Jenkins to to my instance in Google Compute engine instance I added a build in my config in jenkins :

```
rsync -vrzhe "ssh -i /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" . login@Host:/var/www
```

And I get this error :

```
Checking out Revision 59cf9dd819fe2168c4c40f716707d58b2b99e251 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f 59cf9dd819fe2168c4c40f716707d58b2b99e251
> git rev-list 59cf9dd819fe2168c4c40f716707d58b2b99e251 # timeout=10
[Platform] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson4502433356962914860.sh
+ rsync -vrzhe 'ssh -i /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o
```

---

```
CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' . login@Host:/var/www
   StrictHostKeyChecking=no' . login@host:/var/www
   ssh: connect to host host port 22: Connection timed out
   rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
   rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.7]
   Build step 'Exécuter un script shell' marked build as failure
   Finished: FAILURE
```

Any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my public key so to solve the problem you need to :

1 - Setting up your ssh keys : run

```
gcloud compute ssh example-instance
```

2 - cp your .ssh/google_compute_engine.pub content into the GCE VM authorized_key

3 - restart VM instance

Thanks for your help

Comment: At least you didn't have any incompatibility between rsync and ssh, as I feared initially. +1

Answer (score 20):

first configure .ssh config file by (assuming you installed gcloud sdk):

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

It will tell you that "now you can use ssh/scp with your instances by running

```
ssh your-instance
```

**your-instance** is in the form of "instance.zone.project", usually.

Now you can rsync:

```
rsync -ave ssh your-local-dir your-instance:~/your-destination
```

Done.

You can mention the user if you like so:

```
rsync -ave ssh your-local-dir your-user@your-instance:~/your-destination
```

It worked for me. Juts do not forget to replace "your-instance" (and your-user) with the correct one.
You can get it through "gcloud compute config-ssh" or "gcloud compute config-ssh --dry-run" or go to your cloud.google.com then compute engine then vm instances then from connect choose view gcloud command. All will show your instance name in the form of "instance.zone.project."

I hope it will help someone in future. :)

Comment: You could mention about the `-z` flag too which does speed up things by enabling compression in most workflows.

Comment: Do not forget to install rsync on the server! `sudo apt-get install rsync`. Otherwise it won't work. If you use the default debian image it's not installed.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a little late, but you can use the `gcloud compute ssh` command directly instead of finding the google ssh keys.

First, you have to make a script that will hide the rsync ssh command args from gcloud:

```
cat >./gcloud-compute-ssh <<EOF
#! /bin/sh
host="$1"
shift
exec gcloud compute ssh "$host" -- "$@"
EOF

chmod a+x ./gcloud-compute-ssh
```

Then you can `rsync -e` to your heart's content:

```
rsync -e ./gcloud-compute-ssh my-dir my-instance:/my-dir
```

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself? It does not work for me.

Comment: Of course!  Can you describe what didn't work, perhaps with a terminal log?

Comment: Sorry, after a little twik in my .ssh file, it started working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your rsync command above uses the -i option for ssh. The argument to -i option should be path to ssh key file, not the directory where the key file is.

Comment: Yes of course -i should be the path for the file i will edit my post but that doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[How to solve rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7261029/6309)", check which ssh get to be actually used, and if that ssh version is compatible with with the one from rsync.

Specifying an absolute path for the ssh executable can help:

```
rsync -e /usr/bin/ssh ....
```

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2071941) also suggests to purge `~/.ssh/know_hosts` in case the server has changed and now has a different key.

Comment: @RjaibiMejdi What OS are you on?, what version of rsync and ssh are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu server to Ubuntu server / OpenSSH_5.5p1 / rsync  version 3.0.7  protocol version 30

Comment: I mean what exact precise complete version number? What does uname -a return? What rsync -v return?

Comment: Linux ns61740.ovh.net 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 29 09:48:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Ok, the thread I mentioned in the answer seemed to suggest a potential incompatibility between certain versions of rsync and ssh, hence my previous question.