# Rule conflict between multiple SSH

Tags: ssh, cwrsync

As I try to use `grunt-rsync`, I come to a "`code 12`" error, my understanting is that I have a conflict between multiple ssh installed on my computer (Git's and cwRsync's) :

```
where ssh
C:\Program Files\cmder\vendor\msysgit\bin\ssh.exe
C:\Program Files\cwRsync\ssh.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh.exe
```

How can I resolve that conflict ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your msysgit ssh version is taking precedence over the cwrsync one, this causes issues.

You either need to change you PATH environment variable or create a batch file to override it.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
SET CWRSYNCHOME=C:\Program Files\cwRsync
SET HOME=c:\Users\*YourUserName*\
SET CWOLDPATH=%PATH%
SET PATH=%CWRSYNCHOME%\bin;%PATH%
"C:\Program Files\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe" %*
```

(Note: the above also sets the home directoy. You should point this to your .ssh (keys) directory)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by simply adding a single line to my `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=/c/Program\ Files/cwRsync/:$PATH
```

This adds the cwRsync directory to the beginning of your PATH environment variable, which means that its copy of `ssh` moves to the top of the list when you do `where ssh` and consequently becomes the default.

For me, this fixed problems I was having running the [`grunt-rsync`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-rsync) Grunt task from msysgit (I mention it in case anyone else is having the same problem).